# Python - Fastest way to process items in array with a guaranteed delay for each item

Tags: python, performance, rest, server, multiprocessing

I am currently processing a list of 600 items. Each item makes a REST call to a different server in which I wait some period of unknown time for the server to get back to me. I am not currently doing any multiprocessing, so I must wait for each server to respond item by item before proceeding to the next item.

I want to speed this up by making multiple REST calls at the same time and then processing them as they come back. Each item is independent so I don't need to wait for one item to be processed in order to move to the next one. I would think that the fastest code possible would make all 600 REST calls at the same time? I won't get any server time outs because I am pinging 600 separate servers.

This is what I have so far. It appears to be much faster than just going through each item without any optimization. Can we make it even faster?

```
from multiprocessing import Process cpu_count
import time

def print_something(something):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(something)
    # Make REST CALL
    # Process data returned from server

def multiprocess_list(items):
    procs = []

    for item in items:
        proc = Process(target=print_something, args=(item,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(cpu_count()) # I get 4

    colors = ['Black', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Red', "Blue", "Beige", "Orange", "Burgundy", "Pink", "Brown"]

    START_TIME = time.clock()
    # Method 1
    multiprocess_list(colors) # 1.60 seconds

    # No multiprocessing # 10 seconds
    # for color in colors:
    #     print_something(color)

    print(f"I took {time.clock() - START_TIME} seconds to complete")
```

Comment: If the task is waiting for IO and not CPU bound, use threading not multiprocessing.

Comment: If you are using Python 3+ maybe you want to consider using asyncio and aiohttp so you don't have to wait for an arbitrary time for a reply and printing results as soon each request returns.

Comment: Thanks. I did some research and it looks like asyncio and aiohttp are much better options because as @StephenRauch mentioned, this is IO bound, not CPU bound.